# CUDA Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, cuda, gpu

I'm a beginner at CUDA programming and am wondering if anyone knows of any good sources that discusses design patterns for CUDA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Modern GPU Computing](http://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/) is good resource for people who desire to study CUDA. You can find good explanation of reduction, scan, stream compaction parallel programming patterns and other interesting things about CUDA optimizations. This is link to [GitHub](https://github.com/NVlabs/moderngpu) for code samples from this blog.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard good things about [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/detail.asp?item=100000000052063), and I think that combining it with the CUDA Best Practices Guide (included with CUDA toolkit) should be a good start.

Sites like Sean Baxter's ModernGPU, as mentioned by marina.k, will help with CUDA implementations of some of the common parallel algorithm patterns (but I would use Thrust or Sean's code from ModernGPU rather than implementing your own unless you are doing it as a learning exercise).